# Name of functional part of a pdf after removing proportionality constants?

Tags: distributions, definition

Let $f(x;\theta)$ be probability density function. Suppose that this pdf contains a proportionality constant $c$, so that $f(x;\theta) = c\cdot g(x;\theta)$, where $g$ is an integrable function. Is there a nomenclature for $g$?

For example, for the Beta distribution

$$f(x,a,b)= \frac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}}{B(a,b)} \propto g(x,a,b) = x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}.$$

Comment: The "kernel" is often used.

Comment: @jbowman Do you have a reference? I would accept a reference as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "kernel" is often used; see for example (and clarity!) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29).  It is also used to describe a particular methodology for estimation based on smoothing functions, e.g., kernel density estimation, kernel regression.  In kernel density estimation it's usual to have the kernel integrate to $1$, but this runs counter to its usage to describe the non-constant of integration part of a probability density or distribution function.